# How to get element form action from iframe with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

Hi i want to action url from facebook like button iframe after iframe load.

```
  <iframe id="fbframe" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?hr..."></iframe>
```

This iframe generated like button I need id=u_0_0 . I think I can get user liked or unliked from this form action. If action="/plugins/like/disconnect" user liked , if action="/plugins/like/connect" user unliked.
    Ex: Liked user

```
<form rel="async" ajaxify="/plugins/like/disconnect" method="post" action="/plugins/like/disconnect" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" id="u_0_0">
```

Can i do this ?

Comment: why would you want to do that? what is the use case? what for do you need to know the liked status? the proper way is to use the graph api with the user_likes permission. trying to access the social plugin is definitely not allowed, even if it would be possible somehow.

Comment: Facebook not give me user_like permission. They said  that "Your app doesn't need this permission for its current functionality" . I catch like user from edge.create function. But already liked user i cant catch. I want to give high speed internet to liked user. When unliked user like our page then i can redirect to my router than I give high speed internet but I cant give high speed internet already liked user because I cant redirect user to my router.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=849g8RASlcE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: luschn do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: _"I want to give high speed internet to liked user"_ - you are not allowed to do that. You are not allowed to treat users differently depending on whether or not they liked your page, or offer them any benefits if they do. _That_ is why Facebook will not grant you user_likes permission - because it is not supposed to be used for such a purpose.